# Rhinoで内部クラスをnewしたい

Tags: javascript, tungsten-replicator, java

Tungsten ReplicatorのJavaScriptフィルタで、[OneRowChange](http://tungsten-replicator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/replicator/src/java/com/continuent/tungsten/replicator/dbms/OneRowChange.java)クラスの内部クラス、ColumnSpecをnewしようとしています。

ColumnSpecクラスはスタティックではないので、Javaなら `oneRowChange.new ColumnSpec()` とするところですが、これをRhino経由でJavaScriptで記述するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

今まで以下を試してみましたが、エラーになるばかりです。

```
$ cat Outer.java
public class Outer {
  public class Inner {
    public Inner() {
    }
  }
}
$ javac Outer.java
$ java -cp /usr/local/Cellar/rhino/1.7R4/libexec/js.jar:. org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
Rhino 1.7 release 4 2012 06 18
js> o = new Packages.Outer()
Outer@12413ffc
js> new o.Inner()
js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@675dd521 is not a function, it is undefined.

js> new Packages.Outer.Inner()
js: Java constructor for "Outer$Inner" with arguments "" not found.

js> o.new Inner()
js: "<stdin>", line 4: missing ; before statement
js: o.new Inner()
js: ...........^
js: "<stdin>", line 4: Compilation produced 1 syntax errors.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

これで通らないでしょうか。

```
js> o = new Packages.Outer()
Outer@1b7071b8
js> new Packages.Outer.Inner(o)
Outer$Inner@3996a317
```